# coffeescript use method in extended method

Tags: jquery, oop, coffeescript

It the extended version of my class I am not able to access newly added methods. Why not?

```
    class Form
        constructor : (@form) ->

            @form = $ @form

        ajaxSubmit : ->
            $.post @form.attr('action'), @form.serialize(), @submitCallback         

        submitCallback : (response) ->
            $.noop()

    class Login extends Form

        submitCallback : (response) ->
            @good() if response #this.good is not a function
            @bad() unless response #this.bad is not a function

        good : ->
            window.location = @form.attr 'data-go'

        bad : ->
            @form
                .animate({left : -100}, 100)
                .animate({left : 50}, 200)
                .animate({left : -25}, 400)
                .animate({left : 0}, 600)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.post` callback is being called in a context chosen by `$.post` and [that context isn't the `@` that you're expecting it to be](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (search for "context" in that page):

> By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`).

You should define your `submitCallback` with a [fat-arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to bind it to your object:

```
submitCallback: (response) =>
    #...
```